# Shopify shortcode for product page

Tags: shopify, product, liquid, shortcode

I'm trying to display my only product's salespage on homepage through a shortcode.
I downloaded plugin from github and installed shortcode.liquid and shortcode-render.liquid.
I uploaded shortcode-youtube.liquid example. 
I activated shortcode functionality by changing liquid tag from
{{ page.content }}
to
{% include 'shortcode' load: page.content %}
I used shortcode [youtube] on a test page and it works fine! It displays video on a homepage through a shortcode.

Question: How do I do the same for a products sales page?
I know I need to create shortcode-product.liquid file but what code do I put inside it?

Cheers for help,
Rafal

Comment: please provide links to the github plugin.

Comment: https://github.com/culturekings/shopify-shortcodes